Hide taskbar and menu for a really restricted user
Hi everyone i want to make a really restricted user and have no idea where to start.
Ideally only able to launch chromium and another app (Citrix workstation).
No taskbar no right click desktop just chromium the other app and maybe restricted shell.
I also want it to be as small as possible.
I'm on an RPI i didn't found a way to a user with special PIXEL setup. Does anyone know a way to totally disable taskbar and right click desktop for a specific user so he only have access to desktop shortcut.
I thought about making a container with VNC and kiosk mode but it make things really complex.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

To remove the desktop stuff like taskbar: stop wayfire from running wf-panel-pi on start up by editing /etc/wayfire/defaults.ini and removing it from autostart0
Note: if you minimize your chrome/citrix window, many people won't know how to get it back without the taskbar

To disable right-click, you could use xmodmap, but it can be awkward to set automatically depending on the exact OS and environment. Look through the steps to do it in Raspian here for example: https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=156706

The rest of your question is not specific enough. Start by creating a user without sudo permissions, and go from there based on your needs
